# R package BH not found for Bioconductor package RBGL

Tags: r, boost, bioconductor

I have had difficulties installing RBGL (Bioconductor Boost library) after upgrading. The error is encountered when `R CMD build` tries to build the (source) package. Running `./configure` from the package root works fine; unfortunately, `R CMD build` cleans the package before running `configure` again.

Exact error is:

```
checking R package BH ... no
configure: error: R package BH not found.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RBGL’
```

Running `./configure` manually I get:

```
checking R package BH ... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
```

In particular, the error arises from this line: `AX_R_PACKAGE([BH],,[${R}])`. Notably, if I remove this line from the configure script, the package builds and installs just fine.

fwiw:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.2.20.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] BH_1.69.0-1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] BiocManager_1.30.4 compiler_3.6.1     tools_3.6.1        parallel_3.6.1
```

Answer (score 4):

Few quick things:

- You need to show us the error
- I am one of the BH authors and its maintainers, and I develop on Ubuntu; please trust me when I say it works.
- When I try right now (using R 3.6.1 like you) I get an error *from BioCManager* as shown below.
- You could try BioConductor devel for RBGL as per [this page](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/html/RBGL.html)

Error Message

```
R> BiocManager::install("RBGL")
Error: Bioconductor version '3.8' requires R version '3.5'; \
                                    see https://bioconductor.org/install
R>
```

*Edit:* Looking further into this all it took was two manual `wget` downloads from the package pages and an installation:

```
edd@rob:~$ cd /tmp
edd@rob:/tmp$ wget -q https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/src/contrib/RBGL_1.60.0.tar.gz
edd@rob:/tmp$ wget -q https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/src/contrib/graph_1.62.0.tar.gz
edd@rob:/tmp$ install.r graph_1.62.0.tar.gz RBGL_1.60.0.tar.gz  # helper from littler 
* installing *source* package ‘graph’ ...
** using staged installation

** libs
ccache gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic  -std=gnu99 -c graph.c -o graph.o
ccache gcc -Wl,-S -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o graph.so graph.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
mv graph.so BioC_graph.so
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/00LOCK-graph/00new/graph/libs
** R
[... few lines removd ***]
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (graph)
* installing *source* package ‘RBGL’ ...
** using staged installation
checking R package BH ... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
ccache g++ -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"   -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic  -c bbc.cpp -o bbc.o
[... lots of output omitted ...]
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (RBGL)
edd@rob:/tmp$
```

*Edit 2:* As you mention the issue with `configure`, I re-ran this by hand after unpacking the tarball.  And, unsurprisingly given that the build worked for me, it finds it.

```
edd@rob:/tmp/RBGL$ ./configure
checking R package BH ... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
edd@rob:/tmp/RBGL$
```

Where is your BH package installed, and why might your session find it but configire does not?   Did you run one as root and one as you?

Comment: Few quick things: I did "configure: error: R package BH not found.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RBGL’".
I never said BH doesn't work and I have absolutely no idea where you got that from.
I am running Bioc 3.9/R-3.6 (your error is unrelated). Finally, I have tried to run the install locally from the source directory, as I said, and it fails.

Comment: Did it occur to you try `install.packages("BH")` ?  [BH is happy at CRAN](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/BH/index.html) and will install.  You may have your repo setup tied up backwards or whatnot -- we cannot tell from the _very_ limited information you share here.

Comment: BH is up-to-date, obviously that was the first port of call (you can see it in the session info I posted...?). What do you mean about repo setup? What information would be useful here...?

Comment: Well it is or it isn't -- R seems to think it is not.  Try `IP <- installed.packages()` and subset the first column on `BH`.  You either have or your don't.  But this dialogue is *not* about an error in `BH`, it seems to me you are fighting with `install.package()` or however you try to install.  Good luck.  I don't think I can help you much any more.

Comment: Sorry if I'm getting snarky here Dirk, but I've provided the information that's relevant imo - it's an issue building RBGL (not a problem with BH) that arises because R CMD build can't find BH. I tried to check that the libPath that has BH was available for R CMD build, and it seemed to be, so I don't get why I can run configure but R can't.

Comment: Okay no worries - as I said I know it's not a BH error and I never said that it was. Thanks for having a look anyways.

Comment: The vote removal / downvote is kinda rude though (whether it was you or a bystander).  I answered in detail over several posts as post as one could given your information.

Comment: One last guess: the the code _inside the configure.ac script_ for RBGL if it things BH is missing when you it.  Maybe it misuses `.libPaths()` though I doubt that.

Comment: My bad - I may blame it on a bad mood and quite a long time fruitlessly trying to solve it. Thanks again, I'll give it a look.

Comment: Can't until answer is edited, otherwise I would have already done so.

Comment: Added another edit.  The most-likely / simplest explanation may be that BH is installed as you and you tried RBGL installation as root, or something similar.

Comment: I've just upgraded to 3.6 so I know that everything (except base) is installed in a /home[...]/3.6/ library owned by me, I got it installed by removing `AX_R_PACKAGE([BH],,[${R}])` from configure.ac then running autoconf && configure. I think I had the same issue with RBGL before, but I don't know if I found a solution and certainly don't remember what it was.

Comment: I looked at the RBGL sources.  They are doing it wrong.  Simply having `LinkingTo: BH` means that R will give them the include directory.  No real need for that dance with m4 macros and autoconf.  Oh well.  And then again -- works on my box (and I never install anything to ~/R/.... but always into `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`

Comment: Ah, thanks! Unfortunately as with a lot of Bioc pkgs there's no easy way to contribute, only the mailing list.

Comment: FWIW report Bioconductor problems to https://support.bioconductor.org ; 'core' packages are on github https://github.com/Bioconductor/RBGL ; the cannonical location is our internal git https://git.bioconductor.org/packages/RBGL . Dirk's problem with BiocManager is because an installed package BiocVersion is not consistent with his version of R, e.g., because he re-used a previous library in a new R?? Thanks the configure seems unnecessary, and is gone from RBGL >= 1.62.1; you'll need Bioconductor 3.10 (`BiocManager::install(version="3.10")` and RBGL >= 1.62.1 (this will propagate later today).

Comment: Hola @MartinMorgan.  Happy to take this off-line but I tend to run `update,packages()` daily so I fail to see how I could be behind `BiocVersion`.  (And I do appreciate this improvement over the old shell hack of yore.)  Is this an issue with the BioC and R cadences?  I tend to be always current with CRAN and R-release, which strikes me as a common case.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel It is almost certainly flawed logic on our part, but how do you determine Bioconductor repositories to use with `update.packages()`? Although BiocManager is on CRAN (it's supposed to be 'stable', though that hasn't been the case) BiocVersion is a Bioconductor package to deal as you say with our different release cadence.

Comment: @MartinMorgan  I have no repos for BioC set.  As I said, I update CRAN daily and fight^Huse BioC "when the need arises" (say Rcpp rev.deps check, or to help here).   As a CRAN user I see that you provide some tooling for BioC use there at CRAN.  I am humbly pointing out that it may not be foolproof enough, and it failed on my (CRAN-current) machine.    As well as on the OP's machine, hence this question that brought us together.  On my ad-hoc use of BioC I do get by with the posted instructions.   Yet what I wrote above stands:  at least in August, RBGL did something that lead to failure.

Comment: Yes thanks for the RBGL stuff. If you don't set a Bioconductor repository, `update.packages()` won't update Bioconductor packages. Further `update.packages()` only keeps one current within a Bioconductor release, so out-of-date 1/2 the time. There are still problems with BiocManager on CRAN, thanks for pointing those out.

Comment: We can (should?) take this offline. My goto tool is a little script `update.r` from littler. There is no reason to not have it be BioC-aware.  If you or someone from your team has a similar preferences for the command-line we could add that.  As for RBGL: I was both amazed to see autoconf/m4 support for R packages (had not before, I think) and a little confused because if you "just" need Boost headers R does it for you.  (When you also need linking as RBGL it all gets much hairier as we both know, that also needs sorting out "eventually".)